# How to get values from MongoDb based on an ID using a C# LINQ query?

Tags: mongodb

I am getting values based on formId in MongoDB using the following query:

```
db.FormData.find({FormID:new BinData(3,"nMVvjlcHGU68zFBBCeYdsg==")})
```

It works in the MongoDB command prompt only. How can I write the query for getting the values from MongoDB based on a form ID in C#?

Comment: In the past I used the MongoDB.Driver library to interact with MongoDB collections. It's a flexible and easy to use C# library and widely used. Maybe it helps you to achieve what you're looking for.

https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/

Comment: Were you able to successfully use the code from my answer? Or do you need any more help?

Answer (score 1):

I have described how to work with MongoDB in Sitecore in [**this answer**](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/1447/104).

### Querying

Applying it for your case, the code will be similar to this:

```
MongoDbDriver driver = MongoDbDriver.FromConnectionString("analytics");
MongoDbCollection collection = driver["FormData"];

Guid formId = new Guid("insert-some-guid-here");

MongoCursor<FormData> cursor =
    collection.FindAs<FormData>(
        Query<FormData>.EQ(_ => _.FormID, formId));

IList<FormData> results = cursor.ToList();
```

Note that I'm using a `System.Guid` object to define the form ID. You should not use binary IDs in C# code.

### Data mapping

The C# driver can automatically map data to strongly-typed models. I assume that the collection you're using in your question contains WFFM data. If that is the case, all you'll need to do is use WFFM's data class `FormData`. It's already registered in the driver, so just reference `Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions.dll` in your project and add the following directive in the beginning of your C# file:

```
using Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions.Analytics;
```